# Expanded toolbar from start in UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

I would like to show the text beneath the icons in my toolbar all the time and hide the three "expand"-dots at the end. Is this possible? Or at least show the toolbar as expanded at startup.

[image]

Comment: I noticed that there is xamarin.forms tag in your question, so are you talking about the [CommandBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx) in standard UWP or any control named "Toolbar" in xamarin?

Comment: It is a Cross-platform app. I think I need to render this one specifically for UWP. :(

Answer (score 0):

To always have labels shown you'll need to tweak the toolbar IsOpen property

Details about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen.aspx

So create an effect of custom renderer and tweak that property for your toolbar

Comment: I would need help doing this :(